# Mysqldump more than one table?

Tags: mysql

How can I use `mysqldump` to dump certain tables that start with common prefix?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hehe, this is kind of a hack, but it works (using bash):

```
mysqldump -u USER -p DATABASE $(mysql -u USER -p -D DATABASE -Bse "show tables like 'PREFIX%'") > /tmp/DATABASE.out
```

Change the ALLCAPS words as needed.

Comment: this other answer is a dupe, but it goes into a bit more depth, I think. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5269543/8047

Comment: @unutbu I am getting the following error when I try implementing this: "mysqldump: unknown option '-D'". Any thoughts? When I run just the mysql portion within the parenthesis it outputs the tables I want to dump - but then it throws the error when I try and use it within the mysqldump statement.

Comment: @dayne: The command I posted uses a bash-ism: `$(...)` to run a subcommand in a subprocess. The error message you received looks like `mysqldump` was sent *all* the arguments -- even up to `-D` which might be because the `$(...)` was not recognized as indicating a subcommand. Perhaps you are not using `bash`? If that is the case, you'll need to translate the `$(...)` into the right syntax for your shell. For example, you might need to replace `$(...)` with backticks.

Comment: @unutbu Thank you so much for your response. I just read that CMD does not support sub commands - so I will have to figure out something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create backup.sh script:

```
BACKUP_DIR="/path/to/backups"

DB_HOST="domain.com"
DB_USER="user"
DB_PASS="pass"

PREFIX="phpbb"

TMP_LIST = mysql --host=$DB_HOST --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASS -e "show databases;" | grep $PREFIX

# just get to database name column (may be $1, don't remember)
TMP_LIST = cat $TMP_LIST | awk '{print $2}'

# Getting dbs
mkdir $BACKUP_DIR/tmp
for db in $TMP_LIST ; do
    mysqldump --host=$DB_HOST --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASS --opt $db > $BACKUP_DIR/tmp/$db.sql
    zip -mj $BACKUP_DIR/tmp/$db.sql.zip $BACKUP_DIR/tmp/$db.sql 2>&1
done
```

Hope it help.