# mysql export tables using wildcard

Tags: mysql

I want to export a list of tables starting with a certain prefix using a wild card.

Ideally I would do:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p mydb table_prefix_* > backup.sql
```

Obviously that doesn’t work. But what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think that you cannot do this with `mysqldump` alone, but you can write a script to do it. What OS are you using? (I'm looking for a solution in linux)

Comment: Also, you may want to read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268936/mysqldump-only-tables-with-certain-prefix-mysqldump-wildcards?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here is a solution using a Bash script (I've tested it in Linux).

Create a text file named "**dumpTablesWithPrefix.script**" and put this in it:

```
tableList=$(mysql -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 -e"show tables" | grep "^$5.*" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')
mysqldump -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 $tableList
```

Save it, and make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x dumpTablesWithPrefix.script
```

Now you can run it:

```
$ ./dumpTablesWithPrefix.script host user pwd database tblPrefix > output.sql
```

---

Now let me explain each piece:

### The command-line arguments

Bash scripts store command-line arguments in the variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on. So the first thing I need to tell you is the order of the arguments you need:

1. The host (if the mysql server is in your machine, write `localhost`)
2. Your user
3. Your password
4. The name of your database
5. The prefix of the tables you want to export

### The first line of the script

I'll split this line in three pieces:

- `mysql -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 -e"show tables"`

This piece retrieves the full table list of your database, one table per line.

- `| grep "^$5.*"`

This piece filters the table list, using the prefix you specified.

- `| sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

This final piece (a gem I found here: [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) ) replaces all the "new line" characters with spaces.

This three pieces, strung together, throw the filtered table list and store it in the `tableList` variable.

### The second line of the script

- `mysqldump -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 $tableList`

This line is simply the MySQL Dump command that does what you need.

---

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If it has a prefix, make a user with select and lock permissions to the table with GRANT like this

```
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON  `table\_prefix\_%` . * TO  'backup-user'@'localhost';
```

then instead of running mysql dump as root, run it as backup-user with the option --all-databases

as backup user only has select and lock permission on these tables, They are the only ones which will be there.

its also safer using a user like this rather than the root account for everything