# SQL query to drop multiple tables and select from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two SQL databases in phpMyadmin, db1 and db2. Say db1 has 3 tables: 1_a, 1_b, 1_c; and db2 has 3 tables: 2_d, 2_e, 2_f. I would like to transfer my db1's 1_a,1_b,1_c over to db2 and replace with db2's 2_d,2_e,2_f.

So, firstly, I will have to select 1_a, 1_b, 1_c tables from db1, and export them as a SQL file.
Afterwards, I will have to select 2_d,2_e,2_f tables from db2, and drop them from db2.
Thirdly, I just have import the file from first step to db2.

I am wondering what are the correct SQL statements for first and second steps? Assuming all tables that I am going to move around have their prefix like 1_x and 2_x, and there are some other tables in db1 and db2 that has no prefix and I do not want to touch them. Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to backup 3 tables or use `select ... into outfile` syntax for csv output:

```
SELECT * FROM `1_a` INTO '/home/1_a.txt'
SELECT * FROM `1_b` INTO '/home/1_b.txt'
SELECT * FROM `1_c` INTO '/home/1_c.txt'
```

or better yet use [phpmyadmin backup function](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-backup-your-mysql-database-with-phpmyadmin). 
and afterwards you should use

```
DROP TABLE `2_d`;
DROP TABLE `2_e`;
DROP TABLE `2_f`;
```

to drop tables in second database

Comment: is there a way I can select all tables that has prefix 1_x and 2_x? As if I have thousands of tables needed to be operated.

Comment: to drop tables with prefixes check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix

Comment: to dump tables with prefixes check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268936/mysqldump-only-tables-with-certain-prefix-mysqldump-wildcards