# Skipping or Ignoring Temp tables when using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, sql

Wondering if there is a way to skip / ignore all temp tables using mysqldump. In our instance, these tables are prefixed as tmp{guid}.

These temp tables have a very short lifespan, they are used for building some sort of reports in its parent application. Lifetime may be up to 1 minute.

EDIT:
It has been suggested that I use the ignore-tables parameter, unfortunately this doesn't provide a way for me to specify a wildcard as the table name (tmp*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip certain tables with mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump)

Comment: @nbk not really, the ignore-table doesn't support wildcard names like `tmp*` due to the table names being unique.

Comment: see mysqldump can't do wildcards, so you have have an language that builds the ignore tables string. Information_schema give you all the temo tables and then build the string. if you have linux you can use https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper/blob/master/docs/mydumper_usage.rst#id3

Comment: @nbk thanks for the suggestion but I want to stick to the official tool for the time being (doesn't look like there is much dev being done on dumper at the moment).
If I was to build the string and one of the tables no longer exist would it error out or would it silently continue?

Comment: @Tom - Hope this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398663/skip-tables-in-mysqldump-based-on-a-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You are not talking about tables from `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`, correct?  Instead, you are talking about a set of tables with a particular naming convention?

Instead of trying to do it with table names, do it with a `DATABASE`:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTables;
CREATE TABLE TempTables.abcd (...);
```

And reference them via the db name:

```
INSERT INTO TempTables.abcd ...
SELECT ... FROM TempTables.abcd JOIN ...
```

Then use the suitable parameters on `mysqldump to avoid that one`DATABASE` (or pick all the other databases to dump).

Comment: Not sure if I have misunderstood  your solution but I am not building the database, only backing it up.

Comment: @TomDickson - I am suggesting a work-around -- put just your "temp" tables in a different database in order to make the selective backup possible.

Comment: These temp tables have a very short lifespan, they are used for building some sort of reports in its parent application. Lifetime may be up to 1 minute.

Comment: @TomDickson - Is there a big concern about accidentally backing a few of them up?

Comment: By "database" this answer means "schema" (in MySQL official terms).

Comment: Anyway, `xyz` will not be backed up if it comes from `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xyz ...;`